# how to calculate standard deviation for ZIP code & complaints in data in R Studio

Tags: r, standard-deviation

### Purpose

For each ZIP code need to calculate fraction of noise complaints due to descriptor that has construction description, then report the standard deviation for ZIP.

How to calculate fraction of noise complaints, AKA, 'Noise:' inside Data, and calculate the ZIP standard deviation?

### Problem

How to calculate standard deviation sd() on zip that represent a fraction of the column for complaints (descriptor)

Not sure how to get standard deviation of ZIP with ZIP is not in fraction of descriptor. My first effort was to group by zip, by descriptor. Then to summarize n(). Not sure how to compute sd() for this format of data.

### R Code

```
nyc_comp_set <- nyc_comp %>%
  select(incident_zip, city, descriptor)

nyc_comp_set$city <- factor(nyc_comp_set$city)
nyc_comp_set$descriptor <- factor(nyc_comp_set$descriptor)

nyc_comp_en <- one_hot(as.data.table(nyc_comp_set))

nyc_comp_const <- nyc_comp_set %>%
  select(incident_zip, city, descriptor) %>%
  filter(str_detect(nyc_comp_set$descriptor, "Construct")) %>%
  group_by(incident_zip) 

nyc_comp_const_gp <- nyc_comp_const %>%
  group_by(incident_zip, descriptor) %>%
  summarise  (nzip = n()) %>% 
  mutate(nyc_comp_const_gp$n <- n())
```

Perhaps organize by this code:

```
  group_by(incident_zip, descriptor) %>%
  summarise (n = n())
```

### Data

Data is from 'nyc_noise_complaints.csv'. Here is a sample.

```
  incident_zip city     descriptor                                  
          <dbl> <fct>    <fct>                                       
 1        11231 BROOKLYN Noise: Construction Before/After Hours (NM1)
 2        10454 BRONX    Noise: Construction Before/After Hours (NM1)
 3        11234 BROOKLYN Noise: Construction Equipment (NC1)         
 4        11234 BROOKLYN Noise: Construction Equipment (NC1)         
 5        10462 BRONX    Noise: Construction Equipment (NC1)         
 6        10034 NEW YORK Noise: Construction Before/After Hours (NM1)
 7        10023 NEW YORK Noise: Construction Before/After Hours (NM1)
 8        11249 BROOKLYN Noise: Construction Before/After Hours (NM1)
 9        10001 NEW YORK Noise: Construction Before/After Hours (NM1)
10        10031 NEW YORK Noise: Construction Before/After Hours (NM1)
```

Comment: I think your first question should be *"How do I get data in this format into a nice data frame with one column for zip code, one column for complaint, etc.?"* I'd suggest getting asking and getting that question answered before trying to do any calculations with the data.

Comment: Though when you have code like `nyc_comp %>%
  select(incident_zip, city, descriptor)`, it makes it seem like your data is already in a nice format? Your sample data looks a mess, but your code looks like it's already been fixed...

Comment: data format is in nice format. question, how to calculate standard deviation sd() on zip that represent a fraction of the column for complaints (descriptor).

Comment: with columns zip, and complaint, how am I to format to compute standard deviation on a fractional percentage of complaints?

Comment: A warning: your zipcode data is numeric class, but it is safer to keep zipcodes as factor or character class so leading 0s don't get dropped. I'd suggest specifying the column class in whatever function you use to read in the data.

Comment: Good point, I just was moving zipcode to factor() for reporting on charts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a proportion `p` then the standard deviation is `sqrt(p * (1 - p))`. Something like this:

```
 nyc_comp %>%
  group_by(incident_zip, city) %>%
  summarize(prop_construction = mean(grepl("Construction", descriptor)), .groups = "drop") %>%
  mutate(sd_construction = sqrt(prop_construction * (1 - prop_construction)))
```